# how to tune up wildfly managed-executor-service thread pool parameter

Tags: java, multithreading, wildfly, executorservice

I have questions regarding the performance tuning.

I'm using Linux 64bit server, java 1.8 with wildfly 10.0.0.final . I developed a webservice which uses thread factory and managed executor service through the wildfly configuration.

the purpose of my webervice is to receive the request which has large data, save data, and then create a new thread to process this data, then return response to request.  This way the webservice can return response quickly without waiting for data processing to finish.
The configured managed-executor-service holds a thread pool config specifically for this purpose.

for my understanding in configuration, the core-thread defines how many threads will be alive in the thread pool. when core-thread is full, new requests will be put in queue, when queue is full, then new threads will be created, but these newly created thread will be terminated after some time.

I'm trying to figure out what is the best combination to set the thread pool. The following is my concerns:

- if this core-thread is set too small (like 5), maybe the responding time will be long because only 5 active threads are processing data, the rest are put in queue until queue is full. the response time won't look good at heavy load time
- if I set core-thread to be big, (like 100 maybe), that means even the system is not busy, there still will be 100 live threads in the pool. I don't see any configuration that can allow these threads to be terminated. I'm concerned it is too many live threads idle.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to set parameters to handle both heavy load and light load situation without too many idle threads left in pool? I'm actually not familiar with this area, like how many idle threads means too many, how to measure it.

the following is the configuration for thread factory and managed-executor-service.

```
<managed-thread-factory name="UploadThreadFactory" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/factory/uploadThreadFactory"/>

<managed-executor-service name="UploadManagedExecutor" Jodi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/uploadManagedExecutor" context-service="default" thread-factory="UploadThreadFactory" hung-task-threshold="60000" core-thread="5" max-thread="100" keep-alive-time="5000" queue-length="500"/>
```

Thanks a lot for your help,

Helen

Comment: Any progress in here?